# Can I customize the action GNU Screen takes when it alerts after monitoring for silence or noise?

Tags: gnu-screen, libnotify

Specifically, I'm looking to be able to set screen to monitor for silence or noise in a window, and instead of just popping up a notification in the terminal, send that notification to libnotify so I can see it whether or not I'm in the terminal. I haven't been able to find anything about whether or not this is possible.